# Where is it explicitly stated that the terms "contravariant" and "covariant" should not be used for vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, terminology

I mean specifically the terminology in which 'upper-index' objects are called "contravariant" and 'lower-index' objects "covariant" (in opposition to their respective functorial variances).  Everything I can find right now is too circumspect to cite for the claim that such usage is e.g. "often deprecated" as I [wrote](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors&oldid=752886601) in Wikipedia a while ago, so I've [removed](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors&oldid=770018818) the assertion pending further research.

Comment: If the words have a sense connected with functors, what should a Reader be expected to understand regarding their application to *vectors" or (perhaps) to *vector spaces"?

Comment: Perhaps the terminology is deprecated by category theorists, but I've never noticed a problem with it being used in a physics context. A vector is often defined as an object whose components have one index that transforms contravariantly

Comment: @MarkB: One doesn't have to be a category theorist to be confused. I have a smooth map $f : M \to N$ between manifolds, and my tangent vector transforms as $v \mapsto f_*(v)$? Surely that is covariant, since it's going along with $f$ rather than the opposite direction!

Comment: @MarkB: From another angle, the problem is that the usage you describe is not saying that the *vector* transforms contravariantly, but instead the *coordinates* transform covariantly. So it's sort of a misnomer to call the *vector* contravariant. And, if I recall correctly, the "component functions" that map a vector to its coordinates are, in fact, covectors.

Comment: A vector is defined by it's components (and how they transform), so again I don't see the problem. You are right, of course, that you can talk about those functions as covectors (they are functions mapping a vector to $\mathbb{R}$, and so lie in the dual space), but you can always look at the dual picture, so it really becomes a question of convention. My comment was simply saying that the convention in physics is to define a vector as an object whose components have one index that transforms contravariantly. In category theory it's different. It's hard to argue that one convention is better.